# PySpark 2.2.0 Write DataFrame to S3 AmazonServiceException Class Not Found

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write a Spark DataFrame to S3 with pyspark. I'm using Spark version 2.2.0.

```
sc = SparkContext('local', 'Test')
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", aws_key)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", aws_secret)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.multipart.uploads.enabled", "true")

spark = sql.SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("TEST") \
.getOrCreate()

sql_context = sql.SQLContext(sc, spark)
filename = 'gerrymandering'
s3_uri = 's3a://mybucket/{}'.format(filename)
print(s3_uri)
df = sql_context.createDataFrame([('1', '4'), ('2', '5'), ('3', '6')], ["A", "B"])
df.write.parquet(s3_uri)
```

The traceback I get is:

```
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o48.save.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException
```

I'm not sure but there seems to be a jar dependency error. I've tried multiple versions of `hadoop-aws-X.jar` as well as `aws-java-sdk-X.jar` but they all produce this same error.

As of writing this my command was:

```
spark-submit --jars hadoop-aws-2.9.0.jar,aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar test.py
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve this `NoClassDefFoundError`?

Comment: Have you tried including these jars within the fatjar using "compile" scope (to eliminate possibility of version conflicts)?

Comment: Which cluster manager are you using?

Comment: @xmorera: I'm using the Standalone manager since it's running locally right now

Comment: @sgireddy: I can't find anything in the Spark documention that mentions this workflow you're describing. Do you know where I can find something?

Comment: your spark-submit command might be trying to look for jars at the same path where job is submitted, have you placed the aws sdk jars at the correct path and provide the full path. see this link for this error explanation. https://sparkour.urizone.net/recipes/using-s3/

Answer (score 0):

Don't try and use a Hadoop-aws JAR and AWS SDK. different from that it ships with; the AWS SDK Changes too much between versions. For hadoop-2.9.0 you need aws-java-sdk-bundle version 1.11.199

See [mvnrepo/hadoop-aws](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.9.0)